# Catastrophic failure when adding a ColorItem to a list

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik

I'm trying to build a selector to let the user choose from some colors.

I'm using the `RadListPicker` component, with this code:

```
<telerikInput:RadListPicker IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="4" Header="Tile color: " InlineModeThreshold="3" x:Name="listPicker2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Source={StaticResource ColorItems}}" SelectedItem="{Binding TileColor, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerikInput:RadListPicker.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ColorName}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorName}" Margin="12 -3 0 0"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </telerikInput:RadListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</telerikInput:RadListPicker>
```

where `ColorItems` is this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace Utils
{
    public class ColorItems
    {            
        private static readonly ColorItem[] _colorItems =
        {                                 
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(240, 163, 10), "Amber"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(130, 90, 44), "Brown"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(162, 0, 37), "Crimson"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(0, 80, 239), "Cobalt"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(27, 161, 226), "Cyan"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(0, 138, 0),"Emerald"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(96, 169, 23),"Green"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(106, 0, 255),"Indigo"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(164, 196, 0),"Lime"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(216, 0, 115),"Magenta"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(118, 96, 138),"Mauve"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(109, 135, 100),"Olive"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(250, 104, 0),"Orange"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(244, 114, 208),"Pink"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(229, 20, 0),"Red"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(100, 118, 135),"Steel"),
            //new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(135, 121, 78),"Taupe"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(0, 171, 169),"Teal"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(170, 0, 255),"Violet"),
            new ColorItem(GetFromRGB(227, 200, 0),"Yellow"),
        };

        private static Color GetFromRGB(byte r, byte g, byte b)
        {
            return new Color {R = r, B = b, G = g, A = 255};
        }

        public static ColorItem GetFromColor(Color color)
        {            
            return _colorItems.First(c => c.Color.Equals(color));
        }

        public static ColorItem[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _colorItems;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `ColorItem` is:

```
public class ColorItem
{
    public ColorItem(Color color, string name)
    {
        this.Color = color;
        this.ColorName = name;
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ColorName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

As you can see, in `ColorItems._colorItems` i have some commented lines.
Without those lines, everything goes smooth.

(*Please note that errors and messages have been translated from Italian, so they may not be accurate as you may expect*)

But when I enable just one of them, it throws an exception saying:

> First-chance exception 'System.Exception' in System.Windows.ni.dll
>   Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))

and I've no idea of why it throws such a scary exception!

Here's the full stack trace.

```
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(uint hr)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertStringToTypedCValue(System.IntPtr pContext, uint cClrTypeName, string clrTypeName, uint cValue, string value, ref MS.Internal.CValue outVal, out int typeIndex) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.SilverlightTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(object o, System.Type destinationType, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isForward) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Data.TargetDefaultValueConverter.Convert(object o, System.Type type, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertToTarget(object value = "Amber") Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateExpression(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property = {System.Windows.CoreDependencyProperty}, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry = {System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry}) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateBaseValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation = Reevaluate)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property = {System.Windows.CoreDependencyProperty}, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry = {System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry}, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs}) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs}) Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(System.Windows.DependencyObject newParent, bool bIsNewParentAlive)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(MS.Internal.IManagedPeer oldParent = null, MS.Internal.IManagedPeer newParent = {System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter}, bool bIsNewParentAlive, bool keepReferenceToParent = true)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(System.IntPtr oldParentElement, System.IntPtr parentElement, System.IntPtr childElement, byte bIsParentAlive, byte bKeepReferenceToParent, byte bCanCreateParent)    Unknown
[From native to managed]    
[From managed to native]    
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(System.Windows.FrameworkElement element = {Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBoxItem}, System.Windows.Size availableSize)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.IntPtr nativeTarget, double inWidth, double inHeight, out double outWidth = 0.0, out double outHeight = 0.0)   Unknown
[From native to managed]    
[From managed to native]    
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(System.Windows.UIElement element = {Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBoxItem}, System.Windows.Size availableSize)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize)   Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.StackVirtualizationStrategy.MeasureContainer(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadVirtualizingDataControlItem container = {Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBoxItem})   Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.VirtualizationStrategy.GetContainerForItem(Telerik.Windows.Data.IDataSourceItem item = {Telerik.Windows.Data.DataSourceItem}, int insertAt = 0)    Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.StackVirtualizationStrategy.GetContainerForItem(Telerik.Windows.Data.IDataSourceItem item = {Telerik.Windows.Data.DataSourceItem}, int insertAt = 0)   Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.VirtualizationStrategy.GetContainerForItem(Telerik.Windows.Data.IDataSourceItem item = {Telerik.Windows.Data.DataSourceItem}, bool insertLast = true)  Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.VirtualizationStrategy.ManageLowerViewport(bool recycle = true)    Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadVirtualizingDataControl.ManageViewport()    Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadVirtualizingDataControl.BalanceVisualSpace()    Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadVirtualizingDataControl.OnLoaded(object sender = {Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBox}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs})   Unknown
telerik.windows.controls.primitives.DLL!Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBox.OnLoaded(object sender = {Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBox}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs})  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(int typeIndex, System.Delegate handlerDelegate, object sender, object args)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName)    Unknown
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You are binding your Fill property of Rectangle to ColorName (instead of Color?), maybe the ColorName value does not exist/is not supported on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Where is the property ColorItems?    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ColorName}"  ??

Comment: I meant ColorName values from commented lines (like Emerald, Steel, Taupe and so on...) do not exist/are not supported on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: The exception sounded so unreal that I panicked while the solution was the easiest. `<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" Width="24" Height="24"/>` solved everything, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Why are you creating the color if you are not going to use it?

Comment: Who said that I'm not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Fill` property is bound to `ColorName` property (probably instead of Color).

What is most likely happening is that instead of using your custom defined colors, the rectangle is filled with [Predifined Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (identified by names).

So in most common cases, it works because names given to your custom colors match predifined colors! But when it does not match (colors that are commented), no color to be displayed is found and a Catastrophic failure or another freaky exception could happened ;)